# Injection text into "URL" part of img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a URL like this: http://website.com/~user/wordpress_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png

What I want to do is that when the screen is smaller than 768px wide, I can change the url so instead of "logo.png" it says "mobile-logo.png".

Is there a function similar to "PHP explode" where I can target the logo part and replace it with "mobile-logo"?

The problem is the URL is dynamic so if I for example, say that I want to add the word "mobile" in after 10 characters, it may not work as url will change so it puts it in the wrong place.

Is there a bit of javascript/jQuery to simply do this?
Many Thanks

Comment: If you have the name of the image, you can just use `.replace(imageName, 'mobile-' + imageName);`

Comment: if you can ensure that these images will alway reside in the same folder I'd simply explode("/",$the_image_url) and implode it again after changing/prepending element #7 .. or whatever (depending on if you have the hostname in the url it'd be higher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css. Just use two `<img>` for this issue, like this:

HTML:

```
<img class="show-on-desktop" src="http://website.com/~user/wordpress_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png" />
<img class="show-on-mobile" src="http://website.com/~user/wordpress_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mobile-logo.png" />
```

CSS:

```
.show-on-mobile{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .show-on-desktop{
        display: none;
    }

    .show-on-mobile{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5kb6ndsp/

Comment: I very much prefer this version over a javascript/jquery version. Media queries are __built__ for responsive design. Well done. I would perhaps suggest removing the `only screen and` as the smaller logo would probably be better for other device types as well? i.e. `@media (max-width: 768px) { ~ }`

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of this because I am using Wordpress, but I can just edit header.php and add this myself as adding js is not efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would definetly have done this kind of treatment on the server side, but if you MUST do it on the client side, here's a simple jQuery statement to do that

```
$("img").each(function(i, img){
    var originalLink = $(img).attr("href");
    var fileName = originalLink.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
    $(img).attr("href", originalLink.replace(fileName, "mobile-" + fileName));
    console.log($(img).attr("href"));
});
```